# VR Embedded Android Pano Generation

Tags: android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

My idea is to embed a Virtual Reality Pano into a Google VR View: https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview including a pano.

The plan is to automatically create the used 180° Pano by input parameter. So an easy example would be simply showing a name on a pano in a view inside the app.

The pano background doesn't have to be any special kind of thing it could also be white, but would it be possible to create a "name"-overlay on the vr image inside Android before showing the vr image in the VR view?

I think only two ways may be possible, at first modifying the pano with some image tool in Android before loading it into VR View, on the second hand dynamically add to Unity View, is any of this operations possible?

Comment: dont ask for opinions, instead show us what you have tried and where you need help

Comment: Hi @petey, my problem is the overlay creation. I can't find a way to do so.